# Datomic valueType

Tags: clojure, datomic

When trying to persist a list of node entities with a :threshold attribute defined thus in the schema:

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident :node/threshold
 :db/valueType :db.type/long
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
 :db/fulltext false
 :db/doc "Threshold"
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

i get the following error:

```
CompilerException java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
:db.error/wrong-type-for-attribute Value 90 is not a valid :int 
for attribute :node/threshold
```

I use the following code:

```
(defn store-tree [tree]
  @(d/transact dbconn/conn (into [] (vals tree))))
(store-tree parsed-tree-with-refs)
```

where tree is a map of node names to nodes.

Curiously enough, i took the EDN for the specific entity with :node threshold 90 from the REPL and manually transact'ed it, and it worked without any problems. I used this code:

```
@(d/transact dbconn/conn [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user),
  :node/threshold 90, :node/location "US"}])
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks,
Vitaliy.

Comment: Can you provide the entity's map rep and/or the code you're using to persist/transact in the non-working/working cases?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've changed the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I'm still a little confused about "tree", described as "map of node names to nodes." What is the output of (into [] (vals tree))? Is it a list of lists (vector of vectors) or a list of maps? Does it produce a transaction identical to your REPL test?

Comment: Output of of (into [] (vals tree)) is:

[{:node/threshold 90, :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -51], :node/location }, {other nodes...}]

I just noticed that some map values are empty (e.g. in this case :node/location). Could it be the cause? Will try to set a default string.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with {:db/valueType :db.type/long}. @siphiuel how did you solve it? transact code: (transact @db/connection [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user], :bankai/email email} {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user], :bankai/amount amount}])

Comment: I solved it. It was a string ^^', so I just converted it to an int!